# How to Get Azure AD Object by Object ID Using Azure CLI

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-powershell, azure-cli

In the Azure Portal, one can look-up an Azure AD object based on the Object ID as shown below:

[image]

**Is it possible to retrieve an Azure AD object by the Object ID using the Azure CLI?**

In order to use the Azure CLI to get the object related to the object ID, it appears that I need to know in advance if the related resource is a user, group, device, app registration, etc., in order to get the details.  For example, if I know the Object ID is a user, I can use `az ad user show --id`.  If all I have is the Object ID, I don't know the 'type' of the object, yet somehow the Portal can figure this out!

While I'd prefer an Azure CLI solution, an Azure PowerShell solution would be better than nothing.  I am asking the question because I'm trying to generate a list of access policies within key vault using `az keyvault list`, but the access policy list from that CLI command just shows Object IDs for each policy... I have no way of determining if the objects are users, groups, etc.

[image]

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you want to get Azure AD resource with its object id, we can use the following Microsoft Graph API

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/directoryObjects/getByIds
Content-type: application/json

{
    "ids":[""]
}
```

If you want to call the Microsoft Graph with Azure CLI, we can use the command `az rest`

For example (I use [Azure cloud shell](https://shell.azure.com))

```
az rest --method POST --url 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/directoryObjects/getByIds' --headers 'Content-Type=application/json'  --body '{"ids":[""]}'
```

[image]

For more details, please refer to [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/12946) nad [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/directoryobject-getbyids?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)

Comment: Thank you.  Note that the `--body` string has to have the quotes escaped or else the call fails.  For example: `--body '{\"ids\":[\"087f593b-bedf-44d4-8732-96ab980f2b45\"]}'`

Looks like there's no way to make this same call using a local instance of PowerShell?  I.e., not using Azure Cloud Shell?  I find Azure cloud shell rather inconvenient to work with for writing long scripts.

Comment: This seems to work using the Azure CLI locally as well... i.e., not in Azure Cloud Shell.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a CSV file with user IDs in one column, this script is useful to look up all users at once

```
param(
    $file = "query_data.csv"
)

$data = Get-Content $file | ConvertFrom-Csv

$userIds = $data.User | Get-Unique

$body = @{
    ids = $userIds
} | ConvertTo-Json -Compress;
$body = $body -replace '"', '\"';

$results = az rest `
--method POST `
--url 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/directoryObjects/getByIds' `
--headers 'Content-Type=application/json'  `
--body $body;

$results > results.json
```

Comment: I'm getting error. I created and uploaded `query_data.csv` - with my valid ogjectids - on `Cloud-shell`, saved your code on Cloud-Shell as myfile.ps1. After running the command I get the following error: `PS /home/mylogin> ./myfile.ps1
ERROR: Bad Request({"error":{"code":"BadRequest","message":"Unable to read JSON request payload. Please ensure Content-Type header is set and payload is of valid JSON format.","innerError":{"date":"2024-01-18T01:16:18","request-id":"xxxxx-1fa9-4ea6-xx-ea7500ea96e4","client-request-id":"xxx-1fa9-4ea6-xx-xxxx"}}})`